# Calculating the data rate for a baud signal

Tags: energy

I have been working on these questions for the past few hours. I am working on calculating the data rate of baud signals, where each symbol can take on one of two levels. I wanted to know if I have worked through these problems properly. Here is my work:

# 1: Calculate the data rate for a 2400 baud signal where each symbol can take on one of two levels (M=2)

M = 2 at 2400 baud, R = 2400 *log <sub>2</sub>2 = 2400 * 1 = 2400 bps

# 2: Calculate the data rate for a 2400 baud signal where each symbol can take on one of two levels (M=4)

M = 4 at 2400 baud, R = 2400 * log <sub>2</sub>4 = 2400 * 2 = 4800 bps

# 3: A symbol can take on one of eight signaling levels. How many bits can be represented by a single symbol?

N = 3, because log  <sub>2</sub> 8 = 3

Comment: This isn't physics but information theory or EE.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't know where to post this.

Comment: it's ok ( but  typo on # 2 : 4 levels instead of 2 )  ... try this [search](http://cs.stackexchange.com/search?q=baud) and the site

Comment: Note that check-my-work questions are off-topic here.